# Interrupt Latency using Debian on an AMD x86

Tags: c, linux, performance, interrupt, dma

I have been measuring interrupt latency of IRQ5 (part of some custom hardware) on an AMD 586 (500 MHz), which is running Debian Linux 8.2.  The results are strange:

90% of the time, the interrupt latency (measured with a scope) in 17-20 microsec

9% of the time, latency is less than 40-50 microsec

1% of the time, latency is less than 100 microsec

0.1% of the time, latency is more than 100 microsec

Worst-case latency is apparently 256 microsec.  (This is a suspicious number).

I tried repeating the tests using an 800 MHz AMD 686.  Same results.
I tried using Linux Mint.  Same results.
I tried setting this interrupt to the highest priority.  Same.
I tried turning off all other interrupts.  Same.
I tried running in "single" mode. Same.
I tried booting with the "init=bin/bash" parameter.  Same.

The whole thing is kind of maddening.

I suspect that the Video sub-system DMA is locking the memory for the amount for time which is required to perform one (large-ish) block, but don't have a good way to prove or disprove this theory, much less fix it.

Any ideas of suggestions would be appreciated.  (and yes, not using Linux is the default plan at this point.)

Comment: Seems like http://superuser.com/ might be a better place to get help on this. (Since it‘s not directly related to programming, it’s likely to get flagged and/or downvoted here.)

Comment: while an interesting problem, without a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve its hard to help. Can I assume that `java` is not involved? Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean [9% / 1%] ... latency is **_more_** than [40-50 / 100] ms? Actually those numbers seem pretty good (for x86). You notice that each approximate doubling of time occurs ~1:10 as often. To me that implies there are multiple smaller random latency causes that occasionally occur together to stack up to the maximum. If there were a lot of them and they were uniform, it should approach something like a normal distribution. It could be PCI bus master DMA from multiple devices, hard disk, network, not just video. It could be other ISR, including system clock too. And, don't forget SMI.

Comment: See http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showthread/comp.arch.embedded/50333-1.php. Couple things to note in that thread: caused approximately 250us hits, and toward the bottom someone figured how to disable it, for one type of chipset.